# Convert binary Char array to integer and double arrays in C++

Tags: c++, c, binary, char, type-conversion

I have a char array containing numbers in binary format. the numbers are in the following format: integer, integer, and double.  what is the best and fastest way to convert char array to an integer array and double array in C++? Right now I am using the following code and it works fine but I think it is not efficient enough!

```
#define SIZE    5000
char chBuf[SIZE];  // contains double numbers in binary format
char dBuf[sizeof(double)];
char IBuf[sizeof(int)];
int count =0;
for (int i=0; i<numberofdata; i++) 
{       
   for (int j=0; j<4; j++)  IBuf[j] = chBuf[j + count];
   Integer[i] =  *(integer*) (IBuf);
   count += sizeof(integer);

   for (int j=0; j<4; j++)  IBuf[j] = chBuf[j + count];
   Integer[i+1] =  *(integer*) (IBuf);
   count += sizeof(integer);

   for (int j=0; j<8; j++)  dBuf[j] = chBuf[j + count];  
   Double[i] =  *(double*) (dBuf);
   count += sizeof(double);
}
```

i think the copying part to dBuf[] and IBuf[] should not be necessary but I do not know how to get rid of them.

Comment: By "binary" you mean like "1011001011.."?

Comment: Why do you think it's not efficient enough?  If you can make sure `chBuf` is aligned properly, you should be able to skip the copying step, if that helps.

Comment: why not just type-cast the pointer?

Comment: Can you provide an example of a "double number in binary format"?  Which IEEE specification are you following?

Comment: @ExP Oops, I expanded your comments...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to copy the data to a separate buffer.
Also, you need to be careful not to overwrite your `Integer` values.

```
int s = 2 * sizeof(int) + sizeof(double);
for (int i = 0; i < numberofdata; i++) {       
   Integer[2 * i] =  *(int*) (chBuf + s * i);
   Integer[2 * i + 1] =  *(int*) (chBuf + s * i + sizeof(int));
   Double[i] =  *(double*) (chBuf + s * i + 2 * sizeof(int));
}
```

Comment: how about if chBuf contains double and integer? how can I convert it to two arrays one integer array and one double array?

Comment: If you know where the `int`s and `double`s are, you can go through the array and extract them to corresponding `double*` and `int*` arrays. Maybe you can even create a corresponding `struct`, which you typecast to to access them within the original array.

Comment: Do you think I can make it more efficient?

Comment: This changes the question altogether. I adopted my answer.